# du -h --max-depth=1 takes long time

Tags: linux, du

When I try to calculate the size of files and directory inside the directory it takes longer time. The command I used is `du -ch --max-depth=1`.

Is there any other way to calculate total size of files and folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

The command `du` retrieves the disk usage of all files in the directory and all sub-directories (recursively) by default. So the time spent by `du` relates to the number of files analyzed. The options `-s` or `--summarize` and `--max-depth` just influence the output of the command (and not the scanning itself).

Some `du` options that limit the file scanning are --one-file-system, --exclude, and --exclude-from.

If you don't want to recurse into the sub-dirs, you can use find instead, which gives you much more control about which files to analyze. But it can't sum up disk usage recursivly.

```
find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -printf  "%k\t%p\n"
```

Notice, that `%k` always return the disk usage in 1k blocks and the reported disk usage of sparse files might be less or slightly larger then the file size returned by `%s` of the `ls` command. Thus '%k' behaves like the `du` command for single files.

If you want to combine the features of `find` and `du` you can combine both of them by something like.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "xyz*" -print0 | du --files0-from=-
```